# What are the exact properties and evolution of a star with 1.23 Solar masses?

Tags: star, stellar-evolution

I'm working on a project where the star at the centre of the planetary system is 1.23 Solar masses. What would it's properties and evolutionary track be (i.e. main sequence lifespan, length of the red giant phase), assuming a metallicity slightly but not hugely higher than the Sun?

Comment: If you have *exact* requirements you must install and run your own evolution model (e.g. MESA is open source and free to use), do a basic calculation using MESA web (http://www.astro.wisc.edu/~townsend/static.php?ref=mesa-web) or interpolate from the *many* stellar evolution code results that have been published. Otherwise, MS lifetime scales as $M^{-2.5}$.

Comment: The "Single Stellar evolution" (SSE) evolution code by Hurley is fantastically easy and fast to use, if you know how to compile a fortran code. http://astronomy.swin.edu.au/~jhurley/bsedload.html

Comment: Thanks, I don't necessarily need ultra-specific requirements, just stuff like radius, rough surface temperature and so on.

Comment: Unfortunately, 1.23 solar masses with a metallicity slighty higher than the Sun is very specific. I doubt you will find an off-the-shelf model. If 1.2 solar masses and solar metallicity will do, then you should be able to easily find something.